# How to make a button disable/enable on click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have html which is something like, not exactly like this, but just to give you an idea.

```
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="ip" />
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
```

the IP field is disabled, I want to put a button right next to it, which will enable the field without refreshing the page.

Can you please help me do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="ip" id="ip" />
    <input type="button"  value="Refresh" onclick="$('#ip').attr('disabled',false);">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
```

Comment: Thanks bro, this was short and easy.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="ip" id='ip' />
<input type="button" name="control" id="control" />
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="submit" value="send" />
```

Now put jquery code at end of file

```
 $( "#control" ).click(function() {
    $('#ip').toggleDisabled();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Give ID for your textbox.

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="ip" id="YourID"/>
```

And in jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#YourButtonID').click(function(){
    if($('#YourID').prop('disabled'))
         $('#YourID').prop('disabled', false)
    else
         $('#YourID').prop('disabled', true)
         //Do nothing if not required.  

    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider your buttons as shown below:

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="ip" /> <input type="button" id="myButton" />
```

Now, on clicking button right next to it you have to remove the disabled attribute of ip button in jquery as:

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    $("input[name='ip']").removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

That's it..!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `attr("disabled",false)` to remove `disabled` attribute

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vqdat169/gjc8h3d9/)

Comment: `removeAttr('disabled')` would be a bit cleaner. This could go as a comment rather than answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
function enable(){
    $('#ip').prop("disabled",false);
}
 </script>
 <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="ip" id="ip" />
 <input type="button"  value="Refresh" onclick="enable();">
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/qx66w0h0/) for a working example and a possible solution using javascript.

Check this [jQuery 1.6+](http://jsfiddle.net/tjtre6v0/) using jQuery 1.6+.
If you want to use jQuery 1.5-, just change `prop` by `attr`.

Hope it useful!